# Optimize wildcard searching for a NVARCHAR(MAX) column

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2014, performance, full-text-search, query-performance

I have been asked to improve the searching capabilities of a `LIKE '%SOMETEXT%'` predicate on an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column. I am aware of full text indexes but am not sure if they are the best strategy.

A traditional rowstore index obviously wouldn't do the job given that `NVARCHAR(MAX)` isn't an acceptable index key value and also I'd be searching using (`LIKE '%SOME TEXT%'`) so I wouldn't be able to write a sargable statement.

Is a full text index the best option for this case?

Comment: Even if it were `NVARCHAR(50)` it still wouldn't matter as the index wouldn't be used due to the leading wildcard (i.e. the `LIKE '%...`). Also, if it is an `NVARCHAR` column, then the string literal of the `LIKE` should be prefixed with a capital "N" (i.e. `LIKE N'%SOME...`).

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.

It is the best built in way.

You COULD handle it on application layer and ALSO store the text in something made for that (i.e. a search engine style like Lucene).

You COULD roll your own. Trigram/Trigraph style. Will use a lot of programming and a lot of space, but will make queries faster.

[One way to get an index seek for a leading %wildcard by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/02/sql-indexes/seek-leading-wildcard-sql-server)

[Trigram Wildcard String Search in SQL Server by Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search)

Have what you need to get started there ;)